# Update in-app Content IOS

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, push

I am making an app for the iPhone and I wanted to update messages in the app everyday. For example, news apps update new articles everyday, or some apps have a message of the day. Can someone please send me into the right direction on how I go about do this? the only information I find is about push notifications but noting about updating content in the app.

Comment: Are you asking how to load content from a server? It's hard to believe that you couldn't find information about that. Start with the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FConceptual%2FURLLoadingSystem%2FURLLoadingSystem.html).

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you are trying to do. For simplicity sake lets say that you want to show a pop-up message that says "hey we have a new app XXX in appstore now".

the way you would do this is

- Need to have a server where you place a file called news.txt. Ftp the file over from your computer over to your server
- Change your app code so that the first thing it does it connects to your server and reads the contents of news.txt file
- Use that text and show it in as the body of your pop-up message
- That's it you are done & set.
- Now every time you need to give users some new news then just ftp and update news.txt file
- You can even have another file called show_popups.txt in which you can have either 1 or 0. Depending on the value you can show news.txt pop-up or not. That way you can show pop-ups for a period of time and then turn them off remotely.

I have implemented such feature in some of my apps.